# How can I change my project 'expo' to ' normal'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

I have a project which is created by expo init but I don't want use expo anymore and I wanna get a build from xcode. How can I change this expo to normal project

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can eject from expo.

From your terminal if you have the expo cli

```
expo eject
```

You can read about this here [Ejecting to ExpoKit](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/expokit/eject/#__next).

Comment: After I run expo eject, I build my project and get an error  'bundling failed: Error: Unable to resolve module `expo` from `/Users/atakan/Projeler/mobile-wallet-master/app/Login.js`: Module `expo` does not exist in the Haste module map'. How can I solve that

Comment: Did you try deleting your node_modules and reinstall with `npm install`

Comment: Yes, I did but still getting same error

Comment: Accroding to document if you do not have expo-cli, then you should install it first.  `npm install -g expo-cli` should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Using very simple command, you can change "Expo" to "Normal".

Open the terminal and run `expo eject`  in the project directory.